# How can I provide the initial data to a Django model?

Tags: django, django-models

I have read have read [this documentation from Django on providing initial SQL data](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/initial-data/#providing-initial-sql-data)

direc tree :

```
    |-- manage.py
    |-- mydb
    |-- QAapp
    |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |-- __init__.pyc
    |   |-- migrations
    |   |   |-- 0001_initial.py
    |   |   |-- 0001_initial.pyc
    |   |   |-- 0002_auto__add_report__add_questioncontainer.py
    |   |   |-- 0002_auto__add_report__add_questioncontainer.pyc
    |   |   |-- __init__.py
    |   |   `-- __init__.pyc
    |   |-- models.py
    |   |-- models.pyc
    |   |-- sql
    |   |   |-- questioncontainer.sql
    |   |   `-- scrap.py
    |   |-- tests.py
    |   `-- views.py
    `-- QAsite
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- __init__.pyc
        |-- settings.py
        |-- settings.pyc
        |-- urls.py
        `-- wsgi.py
```

Model file :

```
from django.db import models
class QuestionContainer(models.Model):
    topic           = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subtopic        = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    question        = models.TextField()
    options         = models.TextField()
    correct_answer  = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    total_attempts  = models.IntegerField()
    solved          = models.IntegerField()
    level           = models.IntegerField()

class Report(models.Model):
    name                = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email               = models.EmailField()
    content             = models.TextField()
    QuestionContainer   = models.ForeignKey(QuestionContainer)
```

`questioncontainer.sql` contains

```sql
INSERT INTO QAapp_QuestionContainer(topic, subtopic, question, options, 
correct_answer, total_attempts, solved, level) VALUES ('general-aptitude', 'age-problems', 
'The Average age of a class of 22 students in 21 years. The average increases by 1
when the teachers age also included. What is the age of the teacher?', 
'A. 44 C. 41 B. 43 D. 40', '[A]', 0, 0, 0);
```

The question is, do I need to add something to `manage.py` [or] execute some command from shell [or] any other thing in order to populate table with those insert queries?

I have tried :
`python manage.py sqlall`
`python manage.py syncdb`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to run:

```
python manage.py syncdb
```

which will create all tables and then run your sql script..

**Update:**

Since you use south, it seems that south takes control of syncdb and provides migrate instead does imitate syncdb and load sql files after creating tables. I found this snippet on DjangoSnippets which let you do the same thing with south. Take into consideration the notes on the right side of the page where you might need to change sql files names.
This code posted on 2011 and I am not sure if this is still the case with south.

http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2311/

Comment: where to put that function ?? in models.py ??